# IOS 8, Xocde6 : UItextview and data is not getting shown up on the screen

Tags: ios8, storyboard, xcode6, uitextview, uistoryboard

I am newbie and I am working on an IOS app. I am trying to display a header(text data), body (text data) on two different UItextviews. I could able to send the text successfully to the views but, when I try to run the code on the simulator it is only showing the header part but not showing up the body part on the page.

The following is the file where I am initializing.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>

@interface AdvActionViewController : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UITextView *header;
    IBOutlet UITextView *body;

}
```

The following is the updateView

```
#import "AdvUpdateViewController.h"
#import "AdvAPIClient.h"

@implementation AdvUpdateViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    header.text = @"Subject"
    body.text = @"HEllo Text";


}
- (BOOL)showsBanner {
    return NO;
}
@end
```

This is the image for the story board reference outlet. https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGfPr.jpg
Screenshot of storyboard: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIFki.jpg

If I run code and and test it on the emulator I could only able to see the header part but not the body part.

Please let me how to debug this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The screenshot for the page on the emulator: http://imgur.com/4NhYVRG

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing `self` when you are trying to access `header.text` and `body.text`.

```
#import "AdvUpdateViewController.h"
#import "AdvAPIClient.h"

@implementation AdvUpdateViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.header.text = @"Subject"
    self.body.text = @"HEllo Text";
}

- (BOOL)showsBanner {
    return NO;
}
@end
```

Comment: Please add at least some information explaining why this code does reply to the question.